# Repeated applications of Egoroff's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have the following problem:

> Let $\{ f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $E$ that converges to the real-valued $f$ pointwise on $E$.  Show that $E = E_{0} \cup \left( \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_{k} \right)$, where all sets $E_{0}$, $E_{1}, \cdots$ are measurable, and $\{f_{n} \}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on each $E_{k}$ 
>   if $k>0$, and $m(E_{0}) = 0$.

Now, the way to approach this problem is by a repeated application of Egoroff's Theorem.

So, if $\{f_{n}\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $E$ that converges pointwise on $E$ to the real-valued function $f$, then by Egoroff's Theorem, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ a closed set $E_{1}$ contained in $E$ on which $f_{n} \to f$ uniformly, and such that $m(E\backslash E_{1})<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Further, since all closed sets are measurable, $E_{1}$ is measurable.

Since uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, $\{f_{n}\}$ also converges pointwise to $f$ on $E_{1}$.  Thus, $\exists$ a closed set $E_{2}\subset E_{1}$ such that $f_{n} \to f$ uniformly on $E_{2}$ and $m(E_{1} \backslash E_{2}) < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$.

If we keep proceeding in this manner, eventually, we get that $E = (\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} E_{k}) \cup E_{0}$, and I'm trying to figure out what $E_{0}$ is and how to show that its measure is zero.

My professor gave me the hint that the complement of their union is going to have measure 0 and I will need to explain why.  However, I'm not sure what he means by the complement of their union. The complement of which union?? The complement of the union of the $E_{k-1}\backslash E_{k}$'s? The complement of $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} E_{k}$? That part is unclear to me. And in any case, I still am unsure how to show the measure of this part equals 0.

Please help!!! I need this explained to me thoroughly and detailed as though you were explaining it to a completely clueless person. A complete solution would be best, since I already have most of it except for this part.

Comment: $E$ is a set of finite measure, presumably? (It would also work with $\sigma$-finite measure with a small modification.) Taking $E_2 \subset E_1$ is the wrong approach. You should either take $E_{k+1} \supset E_k$ for all $k$, or not care about the relation between the $E_k$ and only consider $m(E\setminus E_k)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, well, that's what Lusin's Theorem tells us: that there is a closed set contained in the set on which fn converges pointwise on which fn converges uniformly. So, I don't think I have a choice to take $E_{k+1}\subset E_{k}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, it could also be that I am not making the $m(E_{1}\backslash E_{2})$ less than the right thing. Maybe instead of  $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{2}}$ (i.e., taking epsilon over powers of 2), I should take $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$, but I still don't see that helping.  The thing is, the way that I'm doing it now, I believe all the complements are disjoint.

Comment: If you take $E_{k+1}\subset E_k$, then all your sets are subsets of $E_1$, and $\bigcup E_k = E_1$, but generally, you can't have $m(E\setminus E_1) = 0$. You _must_ step outside $E_1$, then outside $E_2$ etc. to achieve $m\bigl( E \setminus \bigcup E_k\bigr) = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, if you would be willing to share an amended proof done the way you're suggestion, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: Consider a sequence $(\epsilon_k)$ of positive numbers. For each $k$, by Egorov's theorem there is an $E_k$ with $m(E\setminus E_k) < \epsilon_k$ such that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $E_k$. What do you need to finish things off?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I realized that I was visualizing the whole thing wrong. The sets $E_{k}$ did need to be like you said, with $E_{1}$ contained in all the others. Once I was able to visualize it properly, everything fell into place. Thank you for being so patient with me!